# Base class variable initialize with derived class

Tags: java, c#

can somebody explain me the mechanism what will happen when base class object initializes with derived class. what will be type of object and is object behave as a base or derived ?

Comment: How about writing a code and debugging it yourself?

Comment: "base class object initializes with derived class" or _base class reference initializes with derived class object_?

Comment: You should bother to read [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of an object does not change, so the object will behave as an object of the derived class.

But since the type of the variable is the base class, class members of the derived class can't be accessed directly. Therefore, you will have to declare methods in the base class and override them in the derived class to use features of the derived class.

Note that this applies only to languages with statically typed variables like Java, C++, C#.

Below is a simple example in Java:

```
class BaseClass {

    public void info() {
        System.out.println("base class");
    }
}

class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {

    @Override
    public void info() {
        System.out.println("derived class");
    }

    public void specialMethod() {
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseClass b = new DerivedClass();
        b.info();
        System.out.println("Type of b: " + b.getClass());
        // not allowed:
        // b.specialMethod();
    }
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
derived class
Type of b: class DerivedClass
```